# Arduino - Function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, rfid

I am trying to make an Arduino rfid door lock, with arduino uno, stepper motor, funduino rfid-rc522. Here is the code:

```
//declare variables for the motor pins
int motorPin1 = 6;    // Blue   - 28BYJ48 pin 1
int motorPin2 = 7;    // Pink   - 28BYJ48 pin 2
int motorPin3 = 8;    // Yellow - 28BYJ48 pin 3
int motorPin4 = 9;    // Orange - 28BYJ48 pin 4
                        // Red    - 28BYJ48 pin 5 (VCC)
int motorSpeed = 1500
;  //variable to set stepper speed
int count = 0;          // count of steps made
int countsperrev = 12; // number of steps per full revolution
int lookup[8] = {B01000, B01100, B00100, B00110, B00010, B00011, B00001, B01001};

#include <RFID.h>

/*  
 * Read a card using a mfrc522 reader on your SPI interface  
  * Pin layout should be as follows (on Arduino Uno):  
  * MOSI: Pin 11 / ICSP-4  
  * MISO: Pin 12 / ICSP-1  
  * SCK: Pin 13 / ISCP-3  
  * SS: Pin 10  
  * RST: Pin 5  
  */  

 #include <Wire.h>
 #include <LCD.h>
 #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
 #include <SPI.h>  
 #include <RFID.h>  
 #define SS_PIN 10  
 #define RST_PIN 5  
 RFID rfid(SS_PIN,RST_PIN);  
 int serNum[5];  
 #define I2C_ADDR    0x27 // <<----- Add your address here.  Find it from I2C Scanner
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN     3
#define En_pin  2
#define Rw_pin  1
#define Rs_pin  0
#define D4_pin  4
#define D5_pin  5
#define D6_pin  6
#define D7_pin  7

int n = 1;
int a = 0;
int DA = A0;
int DO = 2;

int state = 0;

LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(I2C_ADDR,En_pin,Rw_pin,Rs_pin,D4_pin,D5_pin,D6_pin,D7_pin);

 void setup(){  
  //declare the motor pins as outputs
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin4, OUTPUT);


  Serial.begin(9600);  
  SPI.begin();  
  rfid.init(); 

  lcd.begin (16,2); //  <<----- My LCD was 16x2

  // Switch on the backlight
  lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.home (); // go home
 } 

 void loop(){  
  if(rfid.isCard()){  
   if(rfid.readCardSerial()) {  
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[0],DEC);  
    /*Serial.print(" ");  
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[1],DEC);  
    Serial.print(" ");  
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[2],DEC);  
    Serial.print(" ");  
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[3],DEC);  
    Serial.print(" ");  
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[4],DEC);  
    Serial.println(""); 
   */ 
   if(rfid.serNum[0]==199){
    if (state == 0);{
      Serial.print("opennnnnn");
      Serial.println("");
      lcd.setCursor(3,0);
      lcd.print("Door Open!");
      delay(1000);
      lcd.home();

        while (a<200){
          if(count < countsperrev )
            clockwise();
        else if (count == countsperrev * 2)
          count = 0;
        else
          count++;
          delay(0);
          a=a+1;
        }
      lcd.clear();
      delay(5000);
      a = 0;
      state = 1;
    }
    if (state == 1) {
      Serial.print("Door already open");
      lcd.print("Door already open");
    }
   }




    else{
       if (state == 1){
          Serial.print("closeeee");
          Serial.println("");
          lcd.setCursor(2,0);
          lcd.print("Door Closed!");
          delay(1000);
          lcd.home();

          while (a<200){
            if(count < countsperrev )
              anticlockwise();
          else if (count == countsperrev * 2)
            count = 0;
          else
            count++;
            delay(0);
            a=a+1;
      }
      lcd.clear();
      delay(5000);
      a = 0;
      state = 0;
    }   
    if (state == 0) {
      lcd.print("Door Already Closed");
      Serial.print("Door Already Closed"); 
   }  



rfid.halt();
    }

//set pins to ULN2003 high in sequence from 1 to 4
//delay "motorSpeed" between each pin setting (to determine speed)

void anticlockwise()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    setOutput(i);
    delayMicroseconds(motorSpeed);
  }
}

void clockwise()
{
  for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    setOutput(i);
    delayMicroseconds(motorSpeed);
  }
}

void setOutput(int out)
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, bitRead(lookup[out], 0));
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, bitRead(lookup[out], 1));
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, bitRead(lookup[out], 2));
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, bitRead(lookup[out], 3));
}
```

I want it to only be able to open the door once, and then it must close to be opened again, but when i added the `if (state == 0)` `state = 1;` `if (state == 1)` `if (state == 1)` `if (state == 0)` the arduino IDE gave me an error of:

```
    Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"

sketch_sep07d.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_sep07d:158: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
sketch_sep07d:181: error: expected '}' at end of input
sketch_sep07d:181: error: expected '}' at end of input
sketch_sep07d:181: error: expected '}' at end of input
a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

I have research the syntax for functions and it appears to be correct, i dont know what is going on.

If anyone could help, please do so.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one or more close braces inside `loop()`. Verify that all open braces have a corresponding close brace in the expected location.